# How to debug javascript returned from server after ajax call in Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, debugging

I have an ajax call that returns a html view like so:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                action: "data",
                view:"data",
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#someDiv").html(data);
            }
        });
```

The view contains some javascript like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var x = $("#something").val();
    });
 </script>
```

Now, is there a way to set a breakpoint on the line `var x = $("#something").val();`  in Chrome's debugger? If not, is there any other way to debug this kind of code? at the moment im only using alert()'s.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just add `debugger;` above that line?

Comment: Thank you thats what i was after. I usually add breakpoints through the graphical interface not programmatically

Comment: There are many anwsers alreay, please check[Set a breakpoint in XHR in Chrome][1] or [How do I debug Javascript which was loaded via AJAX (specifically jQuery)][2]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249696/set-a-breakpoint-in-xhr-in-chrome
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129904/how-do-i-debug-javascript-which-was-loaded-via-ajax-specifically-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use debugger

```
debugger; //this will stop and pause your project
var x = $("#something").val();
```